# firefox (xulrunner, libmozjs) versioning scheme in Debian

Tags: firefox, debian, upgrade, xulrunner

I have firefox installed from mozilla's tar.gz in /usr/local.

I should upgrade libmozjs and xulrunner from exprimental with the
regular aptitude update && aptitude upgrade command sometimes.

aptitude versions handles the version numbers correctly.

But I noticed, that xulrunner, beginning from version 10 are
considered as a separate package with every major version.

Even the bug reports, snapshots etc. have different pages:

http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xulrunner-17.0

http://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=xulrunner-19.0

http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/xulrunner/

http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/xulrunner-17.0/

http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/xulrunner-18.0/

http://snapshot.debian.org/binary/xulrunner-19.0/

And now I am confused because this might be the reason that aptitude
upgrade doesn't found any upgrade for the installed xulrunner.

Is this really such an odd thing?

Do my firefox have security patches if I don't update these two packages?

Anyway it is running all time, and I'm allowing it to auto update itself. This is one of the reasons I don't use a packaged version: regular aptitude upgrades are every 3 months or even rarer on this desktop system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't say which version of Debian you are using.
Also note that can use [Mozilla's own repository](http://mozilla.debian.net) instead of a tarball.

The tarball from Mozilla does not have dependencies with xulrunner nor libmozjs packages; you can, in fact uninstall them both without breaking any dependencies (unless you also have Iceweasel installed).

Whenever you are getting security updates, they come from Mozilla, not Debian.